# MongoDB InMemory Operation With Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: mongodb, windows-server-2012-r2, in-memory

I am evaluating MongoDB, to work with a large data set around 10 GB.
My search took me to this post

http://edgystuff.tumblr.com/post/49304254688/how-to-use-mongodb-as-a-pure-in-memory-db-redis

Which says that if we have enough RAM memory, then MongoDB automatically will start working as InMemory Database, on Linux

Would MongoDB behave similarly on Windows Server 2012 R2 ? 
With minimal or zero tweaking, would MongoDB work as InMemory DB, if we have sufficient RAM ?

Thanks
ameet

Comment: Off topic, since it is not a question regarding programming. Please ask on http://dba.stackexchange.com instead. Flagged accordingly.

Comment: It doesn't work as an in-memory db unless you do the hack in that article to stop it syncing to disk. But yes, it would work on Windows too.